# Conducting loops attracting each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

The problem is the following

> Two identical, perfectly conducting loops are far apart and share the same axis. Each has self-inductance $L$ and a current $I$ flowing in the same direction, so the energy in each loop is $\frac{1}{2}LI^2$. They are brought together and superposed
>
> (a) What is the final current in each loop?
>
> (b) What is the work done in bringing the two loops together? Is the work done on the loop or by the loops?

Here are my thoughts:

1. Since there can not be charges accumulating inside the loops, the current need to stay the same. So $I_{\text{final}} = I$.
2. When superposed $\Phi_{11}=\Phi_{12}=\Phi_{21}=\Phi_{22}$, so the mutual inductance $M$ is the same as the self inductance $L$. And since $I_{\text{final}} = I$, the energy in the final state is $U = 2\times \frac{1}{2}LI^2 + MI^2 = 2LI^2$, so the work done is $W = MI^2 = LI^2$.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: The current can change without charges accumulating, so assertion 1 is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If that's the case, then how does one know the final current in the loops?

Answer (score 0):

1)
For perfectly conducting loops, there won’t be any change in its magnetic flux. Then the final current,$I_{final} =\frac{I}{2}$.
2)
After the two loops are brought together, they can be seen as a solenoid with current $\frac{I}{2}$,then the energy $E=M\times {(\frac{I}{2})}^2$, where $M=2L$(You can check it yourself) The work done by the system is $\frac{1}{2} LI^2$

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer somewhat helps!

1.)
Since the two loops are identical and then superposed you can think of this as a very small solenoid. Using Ampere's law:

$$
\int{B} \cdot dl = \mu_{0}I_{enc}
$$

where $I_{enc}$ is the total current enclosed. Since we are dealing with a solenoid of the sorts you can find the enclosed current in the Amperian loop by: 
$$
I_{enc} = NI
$$
where N is the total number of turns in the current loop. Thus, you can see that B $\alpha$ N. The B field then doubles due to the two identical magnetic loops being superposed and magnetic flux then is
$$
B = \frac{\mu_{0}NI}{l}
$$
$$
\phi_{B} = N\int{B}\cdot dA \rightarrow NBA
$$

whilst the amperian loop doesn't change. Now, while the loops are being brought close to each other the magnetic flux is changing and the two loops experience an equal and opposite magnetic field to counteract this external B field. Thus, there is an opposing emf produced which is due to Faraday's law and the current is decreasing as they are brought in close to each other. Once the two loops are superposed, there is no longer a change of magnetic flux due to them not moving. The B field and magnetic flux is:
$$
\phi_{B} = N^{2}\frac{\mu_{0}I}{l}A
$$

If the flux is $2\phi_{B}$, the current must be $\frac{I}{2}$ for each loop.

2.) 
It seems that all you were left to do here was plug in $\frac{I}{2}$ for your current here. You then get left with

$$
U = \frac{LI^{2}}{2}
$$

I hope this helps!